# Wordpress headway remove post permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've been using the Headway theme to create a website. I used different posts to populate the site with content: using custom queries to single-out posts and display them in appropriate places in my layout.

```
https://204.140.22.120/
```

What I want to do is remove the permalinks from the post titles, because they're not supposed to lead to pages that display single posts.

But headway isn't using the standard .php file structure, so I can't remove "get_permalink" from each custom loop.

Is  there a way to globally remove permalinks, or some other way to alter the many custom query loops in my site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to login via FTP and edit this file:
**wp-content/themes/headway/library/blocks/core/content/content-display.php**

From there look for this line (around line 363 - do a find on the word "bookmark" and you should find it)

```
$post_title_link = '<a href="' . $post_permalink . '" title="' . $post_title_tooltip . '" rel="bookmark">' . $post_title . '</a>';
```

and replace it with:

```
$post_title_link = $post_title;
```

Hope this helps ;)